# JSON with same name as key with different data type

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo, json-deserialization

In one `JSON Object` a value is coming as double and sometimes coming as object where it is an `API` driven with configuration and I am consuming the value but is there any way in `POJO` to identify the datatype to manage for same key name with different data type.

Is it possible to handle in `POJO` level.

```
 {
  "total": 56278160
 }
```

or:

```
 {
     "total": {
          "val1": 92444080,
          "val2": 107372544,
          "val3": 113946624
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when one field can store `JSON Object` and `primitive`, this primitive is just a "short" representation of `JSON Object`. For example only one field is set - `val1` and services returns only it without wrapping in `JSON Object`. In that case you can create a `POJO` with two constructors: one for a single `Number` and one for all required fields.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        Root rootWithNumber = mapper.readValue("{\"total\": 56278160}", Root.class);
        System.out.println(rootWithNumber);
        Root rootWithObject = mapper.readValue("{\"total\": {\"val1\": 92444080, \"val2\": 107372544, \"val3\": 113946624}}", Root.class);
        System.out.println(rootWithObject);
    }
}

class Total {
    private final long val1;
    private final long val2;
    private final long val3;

    @JsonCreator
    public Total(long value) {
        this(value, 0, 0);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Total(@JsonProperty("val1") long val1,
                 @JsonProperty("val2") long val2,
                 @JsonProperty("val3") long val3) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
        this.val3 = val3;
    }

    // getters, toString
}

class Root {
    private Total total;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Root{total=Total{val1=56278160, val2=0, val3=0}}
Root{total=Total{val1=92444080, val2=107372544, val3=113946624}}
```

If these representations are not in relation you can use `JsonNode` type.

```
class Root {
    private JsonNode total;
}
```

and later use `isNumber` and `isObject` methods to find whether it represents `primitive` or `JSON Object`.